# How to get attribute of sibling element

Tags: angular, element

How to get attribute of sibling element?

Below have some code

```
<div>
<input name="nameOfInput">
<app-data><app-data> <!-- I need which this component get "name" of above input -->
</div>

<div>
<input name="nameOfOtherInput">
<app-data><app-data> <!-- I need which this component get "name" of above other input -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way what I found is using nativeElement from ElementRef but this have some unsecurity questions ... I'll to continue seek other way to do this, but in this time thats all folks.